# forced close when direct open read file activity

Tags: android, android-file

I try to direct access this activity but forced closed :

```
@Override   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.log);
historyView = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.historyView);

String data = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("data");
  try {             FileInputStream fin = openFileInput("data.txt");            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fin);
                    char[] inputBuffer = new char[data.length()];

        isr.read(inputBuffer);

        String readString = new String(inputBuffer);
                boolean isTheSame = data.equals(readString);

        historyView.setText(readString);        
  }

catch (FileNotFoundExceptione) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
        e.printStackTrace();        
}

catch (IOException e) {         
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();        
  }
```

However it's working when I access it from my another activity which write and pass the `data` over it. why? what's the problem actually?

Comment: Try to clean your project in eclipse. project > clean

Comment: do you understand what I'm trying to ask or not? =="

Comment: Yes I got it.Have you mention your activity in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: what is your logcat output????